# drag and drop forms / move forms up and down?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've used a script for a while, which allows me to drag and drop divs up and down:

```
<div id="root">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <input type="text" name="stuff1" value="TEST1" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <input type="text" name="stuff1" value="TEST2" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <input type="text" name="stuff1" value="TEST3" />
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    var Drag = {

        obj : null,

        init : function(o, oRoot, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, bSwapHorzRef, bSwapVertRef, fXMapper, fYMapper) {
            o.onmousedown   = Drag.start;

            o.hmode         = bSwapHorzRef ? false : true ;
            o.vmode         = bSwapVertRef ? false : true ;

            o.root = oRoot && oRoot != null ? oRoot : o ;

            if (o.hmode  && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.left  ))) o.root.style.left   = "0px";
            if (o.vmode  && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.top   ))) o.root.style.top    = "0px";
            if (!o.hmode && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.right ))) o.root.style.right  = "0px";
            if (!o.vmode && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.bottom))) o.root.style.bottom = "0px";

            o.minX  = typeof minX != 'undefined' ? minX : null;
            o.minY  = typeof minY != 'undefined' ? minY : null;
            o.maxX  = typeof maxX != 'undefined' ? maxX : null;
            o.maxY  = typeof maxY != 'undefined' ? maxY : null;

            o.xMapper = fXMapper ? fXMapper : null;
            o.yMapper = fYMapper ? fYMapper : null;

            o.root.onDragStart  = new Function();
            o.root.onDragEnd    = new Function();
            o.root.onDrag       = new Function();
        },

        start : function(e) {
            var o = Drag.obj = this;
            e = Drag.fixE(e);
            var y = parseInt(o.vmode ? o.root.style.top  : o.root.style.bottom);
            var x = parseInt(o.hmode ? o.root.style.left : o.root.style.right );
            o.root.onDragStart(x, y);

            o.lastMouseX    = e.clientX;
            o.lastMouseY    = e.clientY;

            if (o.hmode) {
                if (o.minX != null) o.minMouseX = e.clientX - x + o.minX;
                if (o.maxX != null) o.maxMouseX = o.minMouseX + o.maxX - o.minX;
            } else {
                if (o.minX != null) o.maxMouseX = -o.minX + e.clientX + x;
                if (o.maxX != null) o.minMouseX = -o.maxX + e.clientX + x;
            }

            if (o.vmode) {
                if (o.minY != null) o.minMouseY = e.clientY - y + o.minY;
                if (o.maxY != null) o.maxMouseY = o.minMouseY + o.maxY - o.minY;
            } else {
                if (o.minY != null) o.maxMouseY = -o.minY + e.clientY + y;
                if (o.maxY != null) o.minMouseY = -o.maxY + e.clientY + y;
            }

            document.onmousemove    = Drag.drag;
            document.onmouseup      = Drag.end;

            return false;
        },

        drag : function(e) {
            e = Drag.fixE(e);
            var o = Drag.obj;

            var ey  = e.clientY;
            var ex  = e.clientX;
            var y = parseInt(o.vmode ? o.root.style.top  : o.root.style.bottom);
            var x = parseInt(o.hmode ? o.root.style.left : o.root.style.right );
            var nx, ny;

            if (o.minX != null) ex = o.hmode ? Math.max(ex, o.minMouseX) : Math.min(ex, o.maxMouseX);
            if (o.maxX != null) ex = o.hmode ? Math.min(ex, o.maxMouseX) : Math.max(ex, o.minMouseX);
            if (o.minY != null) ey = o.vmode ? Math.max(ey, o.minMouseY) : Math.min(ey, o.maxMouseY);
            if (o.maxY != null) ey = o.vmode ? Math.min(ey, o.maxMouseY) : Math.max(ey, o.minMouseY);

            nx = x + ((ex - o.lastMouseX) * (o.hmode ? 1 : -1));
            ny = y + ((ey - o.lastMouseY) * (o.vmode ? 1 : -1));

            if (o.xMapper)      nx = o.xMapper(y)
            else if (o.yMapper) ny = o.yMapper(x)

            Drag.obj.root.style[o.hmode ? "left" : "right"] = nx + "px";
            Drag.obj.root.style[o.vmode ? "top" : "bottom"] = ny + "px";
            Drag.obj.lastMouseX = ex;
            Drag.obj.lastMouseY = ey;

            Drag.obj.root.onDrag(nx, ny, Drag.obj.root);
            return false;
        },

        end : function() {
            document.onmousemove = null;
            document.onmouseup   = null;
            Drag.obj.root.onDragEnd(    parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style[Drag.obj.hmode ? "left" : "right"]), 
                                        parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style[Drag.obj.vmode
                                        ? "top" : "bottom"]), Drag.obj.root);
            Drag.obj = null;
        },

        fixE : function(e) {
            if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
            if (typeof e.layerX == 'undefined') e.layerX = e.offsetX;
            if (typeof e.layerY == 'undefined') e.layerY = e.offsetY;
            return e;
        }
    };

    function recalcOffsets () {
        var offsets = new Array();
        var elems = root.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            Drag.init(elems[i], null, 0, 0, null, null);
            elems[i].onDrag = function(x,y,myElem) {
                y = myElem.offsetTop;
                recalcOffsets();
                var pos = whereAmI(myElem);
                var elems = root.getElementsByTagName("div");
                if (pos != elems.length-1 && y > offsets[pos + 1]) { 
                    root.removeChild(myElem);
                    root.insertBefore(myElem, elems[pos+1]);
                    myElem.style["top"] = "0px";
                }
                if (pos != 0 && y < offsets[pos - 1]) { 
                    root.removeChild(myElem);
                    root.insertBefore(myElem, elems[pos-1]);
                    myElem.style["top"] = "0px";
                }
            };
            elems[i].onDragEnd = function(x,y,myElem) {
                myElem.style["top"] = "0px";
            }
        }

        var elems = root.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            offsets[i] = elems[i].offsetTop;
        }
    }
    function whereAmI(elem) {
        var elems = root.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i] == elem) { return i }
        }
    }
    recalcOffsets()
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I don't remember where I got this code from (if you happen to recognize it, please do tell and I will add the link).

My problem now is that I want to have forms inside these divs, which the user should be able to edit. Unfortunately, users are unable to do anything with the forms, a side effect I'm sure comes from the fact that the script has to check whether the user is clicking inside the div or not. How can I make the forms editable? Is it even possible with this setup? If it's not possible, I'm fine with having buttons for each div ("up" and "down"), which move the div up and down onclick. I just need to be able to move a div up or down the hierarchy when the user wants it to. How can I accomplish this? What's the best solution?

Comment: https://github.com/aboodman/dom-drag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the mousedown is being cancalled. You need to check to see what the user is clicking on

Something like this should do it.

```
start : function(e) {
    if( ["input","select","textarea","button"].indexOf(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase())!=-1) { 
        return true; 
    }
    /* rest of the code */
```

You probably have to do something similar for end.

Comment: OMG, thank you, this has been driving me nuts for days. I had to change it a little bit to make it work (prepend a "!"), but your code pretty much solved it, now I'm actually able to edit the form: `if(!["input", "select", "textarea", "button"].indexOf(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase())) { return true; }` I still have to study the code better though to understand how it works exactly, but this solves my problem for now. Many thanks! (also, it doesn't seem to be necessary to do something for end, but I have to test it more to be sure)

Comment: Ah, I missed the !=-1, sorry about that.